# Places to ask Linux network questions

Tags: support, asking-questions, scope, site-recommendation

I would like to ask questions about connecting to WEP wireless networks from a Linux (Ubuntu) command line. I wonder what the most active forums to ask these questions are. It doesn't matter whether they are sister forums of Stack Overflow or not.

Comment: I'd say superuser.com.

Comment: There often seems to be not very active discussion there from my experience.

Comment: 8.5% of questions on SuperUser are tagged with `[linux]`, so there certainly are people who know Linux who would be able to help you.

Comment: The question does belong on SU, if it belongs on any of these sites.  If it doesn't get a good answer there, it won't get a good answer anywhere on the Trilogy.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is to use [Super User](http://superuser.com). If you want a non-Stack Overflow Family site, then this question should be closed as `off-topic`.

Comment: SU, yes.  unless there's something about the particular question that makes it [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) material.